# Tutorials.exe windows services

Tags: vb.net, service

I create new project "Tutorials.exe"; when I run on cmd the path:

```
C:\temp>installutil turorials.exe
```

...I get the error:

```
'installutil' is not recognized as an internal and external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I tried another way:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>installutil Tutorials.exe
```

... I get the error:

```
'Tutorials.exe' is not recognized as an internal and external command,operable program or batch file.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Please read some of the other questions on SO and format your question better.

Answer (score 2):

You almost figured out the problem, when you ran the first command, installutil wasn't found because the directory isn't in your path by default. I guess your Tutorials.exe is in c:\Temp. If so, run this command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>installutil c:\Temp\Tutorials.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to determine what version of .NET framework which you use to build Tutorials.exe window service app. Then point to valid version .NET framework PATH of installutil.exe, finally run the command like skjaidev has told